# How to use Python set method on csv data column?

Tags: python, list, set

Hi Ive started learning python this week and trying to understand sets method on lists. I have been through the posts but still stuck.
I am trying to create a set of unique values in column 5 of the csv file (below). I am trying to use the set method to create a unique list but keep getting given the unique values across the rows of the data file instead of unique values down the column5 (Name5) of the csv file. I have tried the append function, but then I get 7 rows of data with the previous row added.
The output I would like is just a list of the unique values in column 5 - Any help please

The output I get is
Red
Blue
Blue
Blue
Red
Red
Green

when I want

Red
Blue
Green

```
import csv

with open('Test_colours_in.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    # need to print unique values in column 5
    my_list = {}
    for line in csv_reader:
        my_list = line['Name5']
        print(set(my_list))

# csv file below
Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,Name6,Name7,Name8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Green,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are constantly overwriting the my_list variable. Instead, you can try adding with .add.

If you want "Red Blue Green" output, try this:

```
import csv

with open('Test_colours_in.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    # need to print unique values in column 5
    my_list = set()
    for line in csv_reader:
      my_list.add(line['Name5'])

    print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
{'Red', 'Blue', 'Green'}
```

If you want unique lines, try this:

```
import csv

with open('Test_colours_in.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    # need to print unique values in column 5
    my_list = list()
    my_colors = set()
    for line in csv_reader:
      if line['Name5'] not in my_colors:
        my_list.append(line)
        my_colors.add(line['Name5'])
    for i in my_list:
      print(i)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Name1', '1'), ('Name2', '2'), ('Name3', '3'), ('Name4', '4'), ('Name5', 'Red'), ('Name6', '6'), ('Name7', '7'), ('Name8', '8')])
OrderedDict([('Name1', '1'), ('Name2', '2'), ('Name3', '3'), ('Name4', '4'), ('Name5', 'Blue'), ('Name6', '6'), ('Name7', '7'), ('Name8', '8')])
OrderedDict([('Name1', '1'), ('Name2', '2'), ('Name3', '3'), ('Name4', '4'), ('Name5', 'Green'), ('Name6', '6'), ('Name7', '7'), ('Name8', '8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
unique_vals = set([row['Name5'] for row in csv_reader])
```